# How do I trigger manual save in Excel typescript for automation?

Tags: excel, typescript, power-automate

I’m trying to automate a query connection refresh on an excel file stored in MS OneDrive.

I’m trying to use Power Automate so it doesn’t have to be manual.

The flow runs successfully, but the file closes before the autosave is triggered.

I’ve tried a manual save line but it doesn’t work.

So I tried staggering delays and saves, but I’m not having any luck saving when I use power automate to run it.

It works when manually ran inside excel, but that doesn’t help me.

```
async function delay(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    let currentTime = startTime;
    while (currentTime - startTime < ms) {
      currentTime = Date.now();
    }
    resolve();
  });
}
 
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  workbook.refreshAllDataConnections();
  await delay(6000);
  workbook.getAutoSave
  await delay(5000);
  workbook.getAutoSave
  await delay(5000);
  workbook.getAutoSave
  await delay(25000);
}
```

I’ve also tried:

```
workbook.save();
```

Like in a macro, yet, it says save property doesn’t exist on type workbook